Can we increase solenoid heat efficiency by cutting it on small rings?
Suppose we have solenoid with resistance $R$ that produces magnetic field $B$ and heat by passing current $I$ through itself.
Lets cut it on $n$ parts and connect them in parallel. Now per-ring current is $\frac{I}{n}$ and per-ring resistance is $\frac{R}{n}$. Hence overall heat drops from $I^2R$ to $\frac{I^2R}{n^3}$. Magnetic field, I assume, would remain the same.
Can you please tell whether it is correct result or not? Would there any caveats in practice? Is this approach employed somewhere?

No it is not correct. If you connect n resistances in parallel with value R/n the total equivalent resistance is:
\begin{equation}
R_{eq} = \frac{1}{\sum^n_i\frac{1}{R_i}} = \frac{1}{\sum^n_i\frac{n}{R_0}} = \frac{R_0}{n^2}
\end{equation}
So the total intensity of the circuit, assuming that you are applying the same voltage is
\begin{equation}
I = \frac{V}{R} = n^2I_0
\end{equation}
With $I_0$ the intensity of the serial solenoid. So, per-ring intensity is $nI_0$. So the heat dissipated by each ring is $nI_0R_0$ and the total heat is $n^2I_0R_0$.
This is probably too much heat and the solenoid will burn. This is because you are creating $n$ short-circuits.
